# How to transform a list of one object to another in rx Java

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

Consider I have an object List`<SShow>` and I am trying to take this object and convert to List`<Show>`. I am able to do it for a single object but facing difficulty with parsing list here.

```
repository.getContentShow().map{
              Show.from(it.shows.get(0))
}
```

Please guide me how can I be able to parse a list to Show object.Thanks

Comment: You should read the documentation first. .map() does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
repository.getContentShow().map{ 
          it.shows.map{ currentShow -> Show.from(currentShow) }
}
```

I think it should do the trick, just use kotlin Collection.map extension function with your list and return it from rxJava map function.

Comment: Glad I helped !